# Suggestion php dom parser or jquery for metabox value

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image, meta-boxes

I have a page that has a covered background image. In the Wordpress backend I have 2 fields for that page:

1. one for a high resolution image – and –
2. the other low resolution.

So far I can give it as style inline in the `div` by PHP. In JQuery it changes a class for high resolution when it reaches a certain screen width.

So in PHP I have to see if that `div` has that certain class to determine what resolution image to use. I found the PHP simple DOM parser might be able to or JQuery through AJAX.

What is the suggested way? If it is in JQuery, how will I be able to get the data?

Comment: you don't need a dom parser ... just update template in child theme to add a data attribute for image info. Then you can use jQuery to do the switching....or just do it with css

Comment: Thanks charlietfl needed a refresh of insight!

Comment: PHP cannot parse DOM because php is a server side script.